# URL de google sites no deseada

Tags: html, css, url

**Acabo de crear un sitio en google sites, realmente no se de programación pero hice lo que pude; el problema es que agregue unos botones personalizados con la URL que genera google sites. Quiero que la URL sea con el dominio "grupoarlo" y no con "sites.com" ¿Como lo puedo cambiar / modificar?**

[image: Este es el URL del dominio que adquirí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta es para el equipo de soporte de Google Sites, no recibirás respuestas oficiales por aquí, sólo enlaces a posibles soluciones o respuestas basadas en experiencias particulares y no generales como las del soporte oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia.

Si ya eres propietario del dominio y esta registrado. Puedes agregar siguiendo estas instrucciones.

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=es#zippy=%2Cutilizar-un-dominio-propio-que-se-haya-registrado-en-otro-lugar

Comment: Así es, yo soy el propietario del dominio. Muchas gracias, lo intentaré.

Comment: Publique el sitio hace unos días, ya realice los pasos en el anlace que mencionas agregando la DNS de google, ¿Hay algo más que pueda hacer?

Comment: Sabes que no has cambiado los DNS del dominio en el panel te debe de ar unos DNS de Google estos los tienes que cambiar en el proveedor del dominio tienes los siguientes.
ns143.neubox.net
ns144.neubox.net
ns245.neubox.net